# Generic class where T : Class clarification

Tags: c#, generics

There are semi answer to this question which I have read through thoroughly, as well as all things MSDN about generic classes but I am still having trouble when a generic class inherits from another class: `where T: ClassName`

For example, here is my generic list class

```
public class MyGenericList2<T> where T : Person
{
    private T[] list;

    public MyGenericList2(int size)
    {
        list = new T[size];
    }

    public T getItem(int index)
    {
        T temp = default(T);
        temp = list[index];
        return temp;
    }

    public void setItem(int index, T value)
    {
        list[index] = value;
    }

    public void DisplayList()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine(list[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

It inherits from the person class:
NOTE: It is shortened for clarity sake

```
public abstract class Person
{
    protected string firstName;

    // Getters
    public string getFirstName()
    {
        return this.firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(string fname)
    {
        this.firstName = fname;
    }
}
```

When I try to call it I get an error about trying to convert a string to a {namespace}.Person which I sort of get, in that I am trying to put a string into a 'Person' box, but how does one call the class using this mechanism?

Here is the main method

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MyGenericList2<Person> studentGeneric = new MyGenericList2<Person>(3);
    Student st1 = new Student();

    st1.setFirstName("Thor");
    studentGeneric.setItem(0, st1); //This does not work
    studentGeneric.setItem(1, Person.setFirstName("Odin"); // Does not work
    studentGeneric.setItem(2, st1.setFirstName("Slepnir"); // Does not work
    studentGeneric.DisplayList();
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

If I cut out the `Where T : Person` and use `GenericList2<string>` it works fine, which makes sense since it is string to string.

Any help would be appreciated

quick clarification Student inherits from Person:

```
public class Student : Person
{

    // Student 1
    private string studentID01 = "001";

    public string getStudentID01()
    {
        return this.studentID01;
    }
}
```

Comment: does student inherit from person?

Comment: Sorry, yes it does. Fixed the code

Comment: the first example does work -->  studentGeneric.setItem(0, st1); the others won't work because they're not of type Person. you don't pass a setter method inside a method argument. setter methods don't return a value (typically) and even if it did return a value they'd have to be of type Person, for setItem method to compile.

Comment: Yes, it does compile, but the value it returns when the program runs, where I was expecting it to be the string "Thor" it is instead displaying `namespace.Person`

Comment: you'll need to override the toString() method inside your Student class, or if you have a getFirstName() method for the student class change this within your MyGenericCollection -->  Console.Out.WriteLine(list[i]); to  this Console.Out.WriteLine(list[i]. getFirstName());

Comment: Also, do you realise you don't have any abstract methods inside your abstract class? what would be the point of that?

Comment: I do, it is part of a larger class, I only copied the relevant parts for this question, but I do realize I specified abstract which would look odd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I would recommend using public properties for your classes, for example:

```
public abstract class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }   
}

public class Student : Person
{
    public string StudentId { get; set; }
}
```

This means your list code would work like this:

```
Student st1 = new Student();
st1.FirstName = "Thor";
studentGeneric.setItem(0, st1);
```

And you can even use this syntax:

```
studentGeneric.setItem(1, new Student
{
    FirstName = "Odin"
});
```

Additionally, the .Net Framework already provides a really nice set of generic collection classes you can use so you don't really need your `MyGenericList2<T>` class. For example, the most commonly used class is `System.Collections.Generic.List`:

```
var people = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Person>();

people.Add(new Student
{
    FirstName = "Odin"
});
```

Or even using the collection initialiser syntax:

```
var people = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Person>
{    
    new Student
    {
        FirstName = "Odin"
    }
});
```

Finally, the problem you are having with outputting your values to the console is because C# doesn't know what to do with your class so by default outputs the value of `student.ToString()`. And becaue you haven't told your class what to do with it, it just outputs the name of the type. You can either override `ToString` or, much simpler just call the `getFirstName()` method:

```
Console.WriteLine(list[i].getFirstName());
```

Comment: This helps a lot. I may end up going with the built-ins, but as with my long-hand setters and getters (instead of using `{get; set;}` I was hoping to make this work with a hand rolled class. 
When I add in the `MyGenericList2` class `Console.Out.WriteLine(list[i].ToString());` or `Console.Out.WriteLine(list[i].getFirstName());` it throws an exceptions stating `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'`

Comment: That's going to happen if you haven't created a student in every postion in your array, otherwise those empty values will be null and you cannot call methods on them.

Comment: That worked ^_^ I am not sure why I did not realize that. Thank you. I did have to use the `getFirstName()` otherwise it just printed the `namespace.classname`

Answer (score 1):

You are using `setItem` incorrectly. This method can be used to set the value of elements in the `list` array in an instance of `MyGenericList2` class.

To use the `setFirstName` method on an instance of the Student class, first use `getItem` to return the object instance. For example:

```cs
public void Main(string[] args)
{
    MyGenericList2<Person> studentGeneric = new MyGenericList2<Person>(3);

    Student st1 = new Student();
    st1.setFirstName("Thor");
    studentGeneric.setItem(0, st1);

    Student st2 = new Student();
    studentGeneric.setItem(1, st2);
    studentGeneric.getItem(1).setFirstName("Odin");

    Student st3 = new Student();
    studentGeneric.setItem(2, st3);
    studentGeneric.getItem(2).setFirstName("Slepnir");

    studentGeneric.DisplayList();
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

To display the list contents correctly, replace your `DisplayList()` method with:

```cs
public void DisplayList()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
    {
        if(list[i] != null){
            Console.Out.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", i, list[i].getFirstName());
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("{0}: [NULL]", i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this helps a lot. However, and again, I am not sure why or how, I think it my be my generic class itself, but when I run the program, the output shows `StudentLookup.Person` StudentLookup being the namespace

Comment: The logic in your `DisplayList` method was incorrect. I revised the answer with a different implementation.